# Black camera feed only from tablet

Tags: javascript, android, web, webrtc

I am working with WebRTC for the first time and I'm having problems with the camera on the tablet. I've tested multiple scenarios:

- Desktop browser 1 to desktop browser 2 (both Firefox), camera shows video from browser 1 to browser 2 and vice versa (working properly).
- Phone browser 1 to phone browser 2 (both Firefox), camera shows video from browser 1 to browser 2 and vice versa (working properly).
- Desktop browser to phone browser (both Firefox), camera shows video from desktop browser to phone browser and vice versa (working properly).
- **Android tablet browser (Firefox or Chrome) to phone browser or desktop browser, video from Android tablet camera is always black on the phone browser or desktop browser. Video from phone browser or desktop browser is always black on Android tablet browser (NOT working properly).**

If it's relevant, I am using an Acer Iconia 10 tablet with software up to date.

[Screenshot: Left is camera from desktop, right is camera from tablet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzjYF.jpg)

Thanks in advance.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.webrtc-experiment.com/style.css">

<title>One-to-One Video Chat using RTCMultiConnection</title>

<meta name="description" content="One-to-One Video Chat using RTCMultiConnection. Only one user can join a room." />
<meta name="keywords" content="WebRTC,RTCMultiConnection,Demos,Experiments,Samples,Examples" />

<style>
    * {
        word-wrap:break-word;
    }
    video {
        object-fit: fill;
        width: 30%;
    }
    button,
    input,
    select {
        font-weight: normal;
        padding: 2px 4px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        text-shadow: none;
        font-size: 16px;
        outline: none;
    }
    .make-center {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px 10px;
    }
    img, input, textarea {
      max-width: 100%
    }
    @media all and (max-width: 500px) {
        .fork-left, .fork-right, .github-stargazers {
            display: none;
        }
    }
</style>
```

```
    <section class="experiment">
        <div class="make-center">
            <input type="text" id="room-id" value="abcdef" autocorrect=off autocapitalize=off size=20>
            <button id="open-room">Open Room</button>
            <button id="join-room">Join Room</button>
             <button id="open-or-join-room">Auto Open Or Join Room</button>                
            <button id="record-message" onclick="location.href='recordedMessage.html'">Record Message</button>

            <div id="room-urls" style="text-align: center;display: none;background: #F1EDED;margin: 15px -10px;border: 1px solid rgb(189, 189, 189);border-left: 0;border-right: 0;"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="videos-container"></div>
    </section>


    <script src="https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/dist/RTCMultiConnection.min.js"></script>

    <!-- custom layout for HTML5 audio/video elements -->
    <script src="https://cdn.webrtc-experiment.com/getMediaElement.js"></script>

    <!-- socket.io for signaling -->
    <script src="https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>


    <script>
        // ......................................................
        // .......................UI Code........................
        // ......................................................
        document.getElementById('open-room').onclick = function() {
            disableInputButtons();
            connection.open(document.getElementById('room-id').value, function() {
                showRoomURL(connection.sessionid);
            });
        };
        document.getElementById('join-room').onclick = function() {
            disableInputButtons();
            connection.join(document.getElementById('room-id').value);
        };
        document.getElementById('open-or-join-room').onclick = function() {
            disableInputButtons();
            connection.openOrJoin(document.getElementById('room-id').value, function(isRoomExists, roomid) {
                if(!isRoomExists) {
                    showRoomURL(roomid);
                }
            });
        };
        // ......................................................
        // ..................RTCMultiConnection Code.............
        // ......................................................
        var connection = new RTCMultiConnection();
        // by default, socket.io server is assumed to be deployed on your own URL
        connection.socketURL = '/';
        // comment-out below line if you do not have your own socket.io server
        connection.socketURL = 'https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com:443/';
        connection.socketMessageEvent = 'video-conference-demo';
        connection.session = {
            audio: true,
            video: true
        };
        connection.sdpConstraints.mandatory = {
            OfferToReceiveAudio: true,
            OfferToReceiveVideo: true
        };
        connection.videosContainer = document.getElementById('videos-container');
        connection.onstream = function(event) {
            var width = parseInt(connection.videosContainer.clientWidth / 2) - 20;
            var mediaElement = getMediaElement(event.mediaElement, {
                title: event.userid,
                buttons: ['full-screen'],
                width: width,
                showOnMouseEnter: false
            });
            connection.videosContainer.appendChild(mediaElement);
            setTimeout(function() {
                mediaElement.media.play();
            }, 5000);
            mediaElement.id = event.streamid;
        };
        connection.onstreamended = function(event) {
            var mediaElement = document.getElementById(event.streamid);
            if(mediaElement) {
                mediaElement.parentNode.removeChild(mediaElement);
            }
        };
        function disableInputButtons() {
            document.getElementById('open-or-join-room').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('open-room').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('join-room').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('room-id').disabled = true;
        }
        // ......................................................
        // ......................Handling Room-ID................
        // ......................................................
        function showRoomURL(roomid) {
            var roomHashURL = '#' + roomid;
            var roomQueryStringURL = '?roomid=' + roomid;
            var html = '<h2>Unique URL for your room:</h2><br>';
            html += 'Hash URL: <a href="' + roomHashURL + '" target="_blank">' + roomHashURL + '</a>';
            html += '<br>';
            html += 'QueryString URL: <a href="' + roomQueryStringURL + '" target="_blank">' + roomQueryStringURL + '</a>';
            var roomURLsDiv = document.getElementById('room-urls');
            roomURLsDiv.innerHTML = html;
            roomURLsDiv.style.display = 'block';
        }
        (function() {
            var params = {},
                r = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g;
            function d(s) {
                return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
            }
            var match, search = window.location.search;
            while (match = r.exec(search.substring(1)))
                params[d(match[1])] = d(match[2]);
            window.params = params;
        })();
        var roomid = '';
        if (localStorage.getItem(connection.socketMessageEvent)) {
            roomid = localStorage.getItem(connection.socketMessageEvent);
        } else {
            roomid = connection.token();
        }
        document.getElementById('room-id').value = roomid;
        document.getElementById('room-id').onkeyup = function() {
            localStorage.setItem(connection.socketMessageEvent, this.value);
        };
        var hashString = location.hash.replace('#', '');
        if(hashString.length && hashString.indexOf('comment-') == 0) {
          hashString = '';
        }
        var roomid = params.roomid;
        if(!roomid && hashString.length) {
            roomid = hashString;
        }
        if(roomid && roomid.length) {
            document.getElementById('room-id').value = roomid;
            localStorage.setItem(connection.socketMessageEvent, roomid);
            // auto-join-room
            (function reCheckRoomPresence() {
                connection.checkPresence(roomid, function(isRoomExists) {
                    if(isRoomExists) {
                        connection.join(roomid);
                        return;
                    }
                    setTimeout(reCheckRoomPresence, 5000);
                });
            })();
            disableInputButtons();
        }
        // to make it one-to-one
        connection.maxParticipantsAllowed = 1;
        connection.onRoomFull = function(roomid) {
          connection.closeSocket();
          connection.attachStreams.forEach(function(stream) {
            stream.stop();
          });
          document.getElementById('open-or-join-room').disabled = false;
          document.getElementById('open-room').disabled = false;
          document.getElementById('join-room').disabled = false;
          document.getElementById('room-id').disabled = false;
          alert('Room is full.');
        };
    </script>

</article>
```

Comment: Please try ice-servers from xirsys.com or other well-written implementations. Because default demos tries to use CoTURN and restund (both are open-sourced). See how to use xirsys, scroll down to see other steps: [http://www.rtcmulticonnection.org/docs/iceServers/#xirsys-without-custom-account](http://www.rtcmulticonnection.org/docs/iceServers/#xirsys-without-custom-account)